# apa6: Prevent lower case for Proceedings references

Tags: bibliographies, apa6

I am using `apa6` with `natbib`.

I am wondering why, in the references, the title of conference proceedings is written in lower case. This is not in line with the APA6 guidelines.

Example:

[image]

How can I change:

> Proceedings of the 33rd annual conference of the cognitive science
>   society

to how it is specified for APA 6:

> Proceedings of the 33rd Annual Conference of the Cognitive Science
>   Society

---

I am not sure how to provide a working example for you, but here is the .bib file entry

```
@inproceedings{ref1,
address = {Austin, TX},
author = {Author, A.},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 33rd Annual Conference of the Cognitive Science Society},
publisher = {Cognitive Science Society},
title = {{A Generative Model}},
year = {2011}
}
```

---

I have read that BibTex makes everything lower case and that one can prevent this by writing `{` `}`'s in the .bib file. However, I think this proceedings-title issue should be automatically solved by the `apa6` class.

---

Feel free to edit my question. It's my first.

Thanks!

Comment: `{Proceedings of the 33rd {A}nnual {C}onference of the {C}ognitive {S}cience {S}ociety}`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I appreciate your braces `{` `}` solutions, but I hope there is a different, `apa6`-specific way of solving this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want that capitalization is preserved in the titles, add a pair of braces around them:

```
booktitle={{Proceedings of the 33rd Annual Conference
            of the Cognitive Science Society}},
```

However, if the style removes capitalization, you should let it do it and preserve capitalization only where it's necessary, that is, mainly for proper nouns:

```
booktitle={Proceedings of the 33rd Annual Conference
           of the {Cognitive} {Science} {Society}},
```